# Catch abstract exception and rethrow in concrete type in Java

Tags: java, exception

I have a situation in my code that looks like this :

An abstract Exception

```
public abstract class AbstractException extends Exception {
   ...
}
```

Implemented by 3 concrete exception

```
public class ConcreteException1 extends AbstractException {
   // ...
}

public class ConcreteException2 extends AbstractException {
   // ...
}

public class ConcreteException3 extends AbstractException {
   // ...
}
```

A method that returns an instance of the abstract exception :

```
public AbstractException createException()
{
    // create an exception that can be one of the 3 concrete class
}
```

And then in my code i have a method that handles the throwing of exceptions :

```
public void handleThrowing() throws ConcreteException1, ConcreteException2, ConcreteException3
{

    //...

    throw createException();

}
```

This code doesn't compile because there is an "Unhandled exception type AbstractException".

To make it compile i was obliged to do :

```
    try
    {
        throw createException();
    }
    catch (ConcreteException1 | ConcreteException2 | ConcreteException3 ex)
    {
        throw ex;
    }
    catch (AbstractException e)
    {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Exception unknown", e);
    }
```

I don't find it very easy to maintain, is there a better way to do ?

Thank you for your answers!

Comment: Way to fix compilation error (maybe not exactly what you want): declare `handleThrowing()` as `public void handleThrowing() AbstractException`

Comment: I wanted to do this at first, but there is so much impact, including in api that are used by other application so i can't change the signature of this method

Comment: Well, the compiler is right, there is no guaranty that `createException()` returns only one of these three types and not any other possible subclass of `AbstractException`. Therefore you have to tell it how to handle this possibility and your `catch`- re`throw` solution does exactly that.

Comment: Thank you @Holger, i'm afraid you are right and this is the "less ugly" solution. What makes it ugly is i know there will never be any other concrete type of exception... but the compiler can't assert that :)

Comment: Did you just add the abstract class to your framework? I mean... if the framework is in use, is must be running right now.

Comment: It is in use right now and the interface is "throws ConcreteException1, ConcreteException2, ConcreteException3", the Abstract exception was there since the begining also

Comment: In the long run, it might be sensible to do what @VictorSorokin mentioned. You should inform your collegues about that and discuss this internally.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the below one :

```
public void handleThrowing() throws AbstractException {

//...

throw createException();

}
```

Comment: Thank you, yes it's a possibility, but it has too much impact on the code, including parts that i don't maintain.